# Editing blocks theme on site does not reflect changes under Tools > Theme file editor?

Tags: wordpress

i was following a tutorial, created a theme and edited the files on VSC, uploaded all via simple ftp. Then i made some changes using the onsite editor and now any updates to VSC files don't reflect on the page anymore.
If i update on VSC and check in wordpress under Tools > Theme file editor. I see the changes there, but it's not appearing on page.

It's like after editing it onsite it created a duplicate of all theme and parts files and saved them somewhere else and now i can edit the page further only with the onsite editor.

Is this how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how it is supposed to work. When you edit a template part or a template, a copy of the file contents gets saved to the database and any further changes are reflected in the version in the database, not in code.

See [Templates and template parts in the WordPress Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/templates-and-template-parts/#changes-made-in-the-site-editor-are-stored-in-the-database) for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much, that link cleared it up for me.